# Get records with month and year - SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table in a database:

Reservation:

```
id | name   |   from       |     to
1  | aaa    |  2013-04-23  |  2013-05-06
2  | bbb    |  2013-04-01  |  2013-08-06
3  | ccc    |  2013-05-12  |  2013-05-19
4  | ddd    |  2013-06-01  |  2013-07-27
5  | eee    |  2013-06-23  |  2013-07-06
6  | fff    |  2013-07-23  |  2013-08-09
```

I would like pass $year and $month. For example:

```
$year = 2013;
$month = '04';
```

This should return me:

```
1  | aaa    |  2013-04-23  |  2013-05-06
2  | bbb    |  2013-04-01  |  2013-08-06
```

because year 2013 and month 04 is in this period.

Next examples:

```
$year = 2013;
$month = '05';
```

should return:

```
1  | aaa    |  2013-04-23  |  2013-05-06
2  | bbb    |  2013-04-01  |  2013-08-06
3  | ccc    |  2013-05-12  |  2013-05-19


$year = 2013;
$month = '06';

2  | bbb    |  2013-04-01  |  2013-08-06
3  | ccc    |  2013-05-12  |  2013-05-19
4  | ddd    |  2013-06-01  |  2013-07-27
5  | eee    |  2013-06-23  |  2013-07-06


$year = 2013;
$month = '07';

2  | bbb    |  2013-04-01  |  2013-08-06
4  | ddd    |  2013-06-01  |  2013-07-27
5  | eee    |  2013-06-23  |  2013-07-06
6  | fff    |  2013-07-23  |  2013-08-09

$year = 2013;
$month = '08';

2  | bbb    |  2013-04-01  |  2013-08-06
6  | fff    |  2013-07-23  |  2013-08-09
```

How should the query be in SQL for this with two parameters - year and month.

EDIT:
OK, i try:

$year = 2013;
$month  = '04';

```
SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE from <= '$year-$month-01' AND to >= '$year-$month-01'
```

but this return me zero records.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have you tried anything or do you just need someone to do your homework as @JohnConde said? If the latter, StackOverflow is the wrong website to seek for "help".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
from tbl
where from <= '$year-$month-01' 
  and to >= '$year-$month-01'
```

It's important that month is left padded with zeros for the above to work.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, i am good at PHP but mediocre at SQL... There is a good possiblity that you can solve this problem using SQL (like chris stated). However, if i was in your position, since i don't know as much SQL, if it was a small table i would pull all records and use PHP to verify.

If it is a large table, then that is just a waste of system resources and i would look into a SQL-Based solution.

Comment: If you don't know that much SQL or are mediocre at it, perhaps you shouldn't post an answer to an SQL-based question